# Call String extension including function written in Swift from Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift-extensions

When an extension in Swift just uses a variable as follows:

```
 extension NSString   {
        var isNumber: Bool {
            return length > 0 && rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted).location == NSNotFound
        }
    }
```

I can call it from Objective-C using the very friendly syntax:

```
NSString *str = @"twelve";
BOOL isNumber = str.isNumber;
```

However I am struggling with the syntax when the extension uses a function as in:

```
extension String {
 func asImage(withAttributes attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]? = nil, size: CGSize? = nil) -> UIImage? {
        let size = size ?? (self as NSString).size(attributes: attributes as! [String : Any])
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size).image { _ in
                (self as NSString).draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size),
                                        withAttributes: attributes as! [String : Any])
            }
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            return nil
        }
    }
```

This can be called from Swift with as little as:

```
 var image = "Hello World".asImage()
```

But I can't figure out how to call it from Objective-C.

In fact, autotype does not even recognize str.asImage and when I try various things, it leads me down a rabbit hole of errors and fix-its that lead to other errors.

How would I call the above extension from Objective-C?

Comment: You should be extending `NSString` and btw your method is called `asImage` not `image`

Comment: corrected the asImage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Swift class, extension, or protocol can only be represented in Objective-C if it's convertible or marked explicitly with `@objc`.. which means it requires all parameters to be convertible to Objective-C as well.

`struct` also cannot be converted so that leaves us with just classes alone (IE: extensions on classes and concrete classes) and to mark a class `@objc`, it must inherit `NSObject`.

Example:

```
@objc
extension NSString {
    func asImage(withAttributes attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]? = nil, size: CGSize = .zero) -> UIImage? {
        let size = size == .zero ? self.size(withAttributes: attributes!) : size
       if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
           return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size).image { _ in
               self.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size),
                                       withAttributes: attributes!)
           }
       } else {
           // Fallback on earlier versions
           return nil
       }
   }
}
```

Notice that I changed the `CGSize` parameter to non-optional and compared against zero instead..

Also note that I marked it `@objc` and changed it to an extension on `NSString` because `String` itself cannot be converted to Objective-C as it's a `struct`!

Then in Objective-C you can call it like so:

```
[str asImageWithAttributes:@{....} size:CGSizeZero];
```

or whatever parameters you want..

Comment: `self as NSString` inside a `NSString` extension is pointless

Comment: True, I forgot about that but I also didn't want to change much of OP's code, but I have changed it as it also improves readability.

Comment: One issue came up. Extension is not respecting font size...I am sending attributes from Objc as follows:  NSMutableDictionary *attrs = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary]; [atts setObject: [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12] forKey: NSFontAttributeName]; [attrs setObject: [UIColor whiteColor] forKey: NSForegroundColorAttributeName];[attrs setObject: [UIColor lightGrayColor] forKey: NSBackgroundColorAttributeName];  Colors work but not size...